# Rails asset pipeline not compiling fonts from 3rd party css framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

### The Problem

I'm using Semantic UI, the app renders icon fonts perfectly in development:

[image: Fonts work in development]

But don't work in production:[image]

### Error Details

In **development**, this file is available at:
`http://localhost:3000/assets/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2`

In **production**, I get these errors:

> planetlauncher.herokuapp.com/:1 GET
>   https://planetlauncher.herokuapp.com/assets/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff
>   planetlauncher.herokuapp.com/:1 GET
>   https://planetlauncher.herokuapp.com/assets/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf
>   404 (Not Found)

### Background

- Webpack was installed bundled with the `rails new --webpack:react` command.
- Semantic UI installed via `yarn add semantic-ui-css`
- `Application.css` includes:
  `*= require 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css`
- `assets.rb` includes:
  `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')` 
  `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/`

Also, I **cannot precompile** assets and must fallback to the heroku assets pipeline because of my react web pack dependence.

Comment: I can see what's happening here, have the same thing myself - any files referenced by css in `node_modules` will not work because it's referenced by for example `url('asset.css')` rather than `asset-url('asset.css')` (which would get the fingerprinted url). Did you figure out a way around this?

Comment: @SamPeacey you're right. I forgot to update this question with the new information I got. On it

Comment: Thanks for the update! To resolve this myself I ended up just compiling them via webpacker rather than using the asset pipeline

Comment: @SamPeacey that sounds awesome! Could you submit your solution as an answer to this question? I'll accept yours, and it'll help a lot of future people out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got around this by compiling the assets with webpack - you're already using webpack, so it shouldn't be a big deal.

Create a pack for the stylesheets:

`/app/javascript/packs/stylesheets.js`

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic';
```

Then in your layout (`/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` for example):

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag "stylesheets", :media => 'all' %>
```

Comment: Just tried this and getting this error: `Webpacker can't find stylesheets.css in /Users/my_user/Workspace/my_app/public/packs/manifest.json`

Comment: @markhops, I'm not sure what your setup is, but these files should be in `app/javascript/packs`, I personally don't have a packs folder in `/public`, the `manifest.json` is a sprockets file that would normally live in `app/assets`, and not something to do with webpack. As far as I am aware. Something sounds a little bit wonky with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you forgot compile your assets. So, your assets is not available in production enviroment.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this would usually work, it doesn't in my case. I need the Heroku pipeline to do my deploying for me because of my webpack react app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a known issue. One of the comments explains this best:

> css in node_modules will not work because it's referenced by for example url('asset.css') rather than asset-url('asset.css') (which would get the fingerprinted url)
>
> -- [Sam Peacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709846/heroku-asset-pipeline-not-compiling-fonts-from-3rd-party-css-framework?noredirect=1#comment78040725_44709846)

I also posted this as an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29563) to rails/rails, and this doesn't seem to be something Rails is going to fix:

> No plans to fix, neither workarounds. This problem also exists with any pure css libraries that don't use rails helpers and are not installed via `yarn`.
>
> -- [Rafael France](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29563#issuecomment-311206054)